# how can I make the shape of a medition using d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

basically I'm trying to do something like the image, I'm basing myself on the image on the left, my goal is to have something like the image on the right.

[image]

This is the most I have achieved:

[image]

I am new to d3.js, I don't know how to make the thermometer shape, I have tried many things but maybe because of my inexperience I get too complicated.

this is my live code:

https://jsfiddle.net/zukdymvf/1/

```js
function generateNumber() {
  let number = parseInt(Math.random() * 100)
  //let number= 100

  d3.select("#indicador").attr("y", yScale(number) - 3); // to center the indicador image
  d3.select("#indicadorText").attr("y", yScale(number) + 5).text(number);
}

let heightRectangle = 10;
d3.select("#visualization").append('svg')
var vis = d3.select("svg").attr("width", 800).attr("height", 614).style("border", "1px solid red");

let g = vis.append("g").style("transform", "translate(0px, 10px)").style("transform", "translate(10px, 10px)");


g.append("image")
  .attr("id", "indicador")
  .attr("href", "https://www.shareicon.net/data/256x256/2015/08/17/86784_left_512x512.png")
  .attr("width", 15)
  .attr("height", 15)
  .attr("y", 403)
  .style("transform", "translate(100px)")

g.append("text")
  .attr("id", "indicadorText")
  .text("0")
  .attr("x", 120)
  .attr("y", 413)
  .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")

g.append("circle")
  .attr("id", "mycircle")
  .attr("r", 55)
  .attr("cx", 52)
  .attr("cy", 450)
  .attr("width", "100")
  .attr("height", "100")
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
//Doing my color bar
var arr = d3.range(101)
let maxRange = 410; // instead of 600
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([maxRange, 0])
let borderRadius = 5;
var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 50, 100])
  .range(["green", "yellow", "red"])

g.selectAll('.rect').data(arr).enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr("class", "rect")
  .attr("rx", borderRadius)

  .attr("ry", borderRadius)

  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return i * 4
  })
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("height", heightRectangle)
  .attr("width", 60)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return colorScale(d)
  })


var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 500])
  .range([maxRange, 0])


var yAxisBar = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(y)
  .ticks(15);
//.tickFormat(function(d,i){ return "" });
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(150 , 0)")
  .call(yAxisBar)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("axis title");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
<button onclick="generateNumber()">
 Generate number
</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a plain JavaScript function that returns the shape of a thermometer. I find that [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) and [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d) are very valuable in understanding how to write SVG paths like that.

The arguments to pass are `radius` - the radius of the bulb, `width` - the width of the shaft, and `height` - the height of the shaft.

Hopefully, you can use it to render your scale inside it, and adjust its height with the new value

```js
function getThermometerOutline(shape) {
  const height = shape.height;
  const width = shape.width;
  const radius = shape.radius;

  // Draw it in two parts, first the left, then the right
  // Start at the very top, the total width is 2x the radius
  let result = `M${radius},0 `;

  // Then draw the first rounding
  const offset = radius - (width / 2);
  result += `A ${width / 2} ${width / 2} 0 0 0 ${offset},${offset} `;

  // Go down the shaft to the base of the bulb
  const shaftHeight = height - offset - (2 * radius); // more or less
  result += `V${shaftHeight + offset} `;

  // Draw the bulb in two half circles, first we end at the bottom
  const endPoint = {
    x: radius,
    y: height
  };
  result += `a ${radius} ${radius} 0 1 0 `
  result += `${width},0 `;

  // Now move back up to the very top
  result += `V${offset} `;
  result += `A ${width / 2} ${width / 2} 0 0 0 ${radius},0 `;

  return result + 'Z';
}

function generateNumber() {
  let number = parseInt(Math.random() * 100)
  //let number= 100

  d3.select("#indicador").attr("y", yScale(number) - 3); // to center the indicador image
  d3.select("#indicadorText").attr("y", yScale(number) + 5).text(number);
}

let heightRectangle = 10;
const vis = d3.select("#visualization")
  .append('svg')
  .attr("width", 800)
  .attr("height", 614)
  .style("border", "1px solid red");

let g = vis.append("g")
  .style("transform", "translate(10px, 10px)");

g.append("image")
  .attr("id", "indicador")
  .attr("href", "https://www.shareicon.net/data/256x256/2015/08/17/86784_left_512x512.png")
  .attr("width", 15)
  .attr("height", 15)
  .attr("y", 403)
  .style("transform", "translate(100px)")

g.append("text")
  .attr("id", "indicadorText")
  .text("0")
  .attr("x", 120)
  .attr("y", 413)
  .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")

const thermometer = vis.append("g")
  .attr("id", "thermometer")
  .attr('transform', 'translate(10, 10)');

thermometer.append("circle")
  .attr("id", "mycircle")
  .attr("r", 55)
  .attr("cx", 52)
  .attr("cy", 450)
  .attr("width", "100")
  .attr("height", "100")
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
//Doing my color bar
var arr = d3.range(101)
let maxRange = 410; // instead of 600
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([maxRange, 0])
let borderRadius = 5;
var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 50, 100])
  .range(["green", "yellow", "red"])

thermometer.selectAll('.rect')
  .data(arr)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr("class", "rect")
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return i * 4
  })
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("height", heightRectangle)
  .attr("width", 60)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return colorScale(d)
  })

const outline = thermometer.append("path")
  .attr("id", "outline")
  .attr("d", getThermometerOutline({
    width: 62,
    height: 532,
    radius: 56
  }))
  .attr("transform", "translate(-5, -16)")

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 500])
  .range([maxRange, 0])


var yAxisBar = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(y)
  .ticks(15);
//.tickFormat(function(d,i){ return "" });

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(150 , 0)")
  .call(yAxisBar)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("axis title");
```

```css
#thermometer #outline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
<button onclick="generateNumber()">
 Generate number
</button>
```

---

**Edit** to fill up the thermometer completely:

```js
function getThermometerOutline(shape) {
  const height = shape.height;
  const width = shape.width;
  const radius = shape.radius;

  // Draw it in two parts, first the left, then the right
  // Start at the very top, the total width is 2x the radius
  let result = `M${radius},0 `;

  // Then draw the first rounding
  const offset = radius - (width / 2);
  result += `A ${width / 2} ${width / 2} 0 0 0 ${offset},${offset} `;

  // Go down the shaft to the base of the bulb
  const shaftHeight = height - offset - (2 * radius); // more or less
  result += `V${shaftHeight + offset} `;

  // Draw the bulb in two half circles, first we end at the bottom
  const endPoint = {
    x: radius,
    y: height
  };
  result += `a ${radius} ${radius} 0 1 0 `
  result += `${width},0 `;

  // Now move back up to the very top
  result += `V${offset} `;
  result += `A ${width / 2} ${width / 2} 0 0 0 ${radius},0 `;

  return result + 'Z';
}

function generateNumber() {
  let number = parseInt(Math.random() * 100)
  //let number= 100

  d3.select("#indicador").attr("y", yScale(number) - 3); // to center the indicador image
  d3.select("#indicadorText").attr("y", yScale(number) + 5).text(number);
}

const vis = d3.select("#visualization")
  .append('svg')
  .attr("width", 800)
  .attr("height", 614)
  .style("border", "1px solid red");

const gradient = vis.append('defs')
  .append('linearGradient')
  .attr('id', 'temperature')
  .attr('x1', '0%')
  .attr('x2', '0%')
  .attr('y1', '100%')
  .attr('y2', '0%');

// Start at red
gradient.append('stop')
  .attr('offset', '0%')
  .style('stop-color', 'red');

// The entire bulb should be red
// a little less than radius / (height + radius)
gradient.append('stop')
  .attr('offset', '8%')
  .style('stop-color', 'red');


gradient.append('stop')
  .attr('offset', '50%')
  .style('stop-color', 'yellow');

gradient.append('stop')
  .attr('offset', '100%')
  .style('stop-color', 'green');

let g = vis.append("g")
  .style("transform", "translate(10px, 10px)");

g.append("image")
  .attr("id", "indicador")
  .attr("href", "https://www.shareicon.net/data/256x256/2015/08/17/86784_left_512x512.png")
  .attr("width", 15)
  .attr("height", 15)
  .attr("y", 403)
  .style("transform", "translate(100px)")

g.append("text")
  .attr("id", "indicadorText")
  .text("0")
  .attr("x", 120)
  .attr("y", 413)
  .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")

const thermometer = vis.append("g")
  .attr("id", "thermometer")
  .attr('transform', 'translate(10, 10)');

const outline = thermometer.append("path")
  .attr("id", "outline")
  .attr("d", getThermometerOutline({
    width: 62,
    height: 532,
    radius: 56
  }))
  .attr("transform", "translate(-5, -16)")
  .style("fill", "url(#temperature)");

let maxRange = 410; // instead of 600
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 500])
  .range([maxRange, 0])


var yAxisBar = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(y)
  .ticks(15);
//.tickFormat(function(d,i){ return "" });

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(150 , 0)")
  .call(yAxisBar)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("axis title");
```

```css
#thermometer #outline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
<button onclick="generateNumber()">
 Generate number
</button>
```