# D3 - Matplotlib like colorbar

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, d3.js

How do I add a color bar similar to [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_adjust.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-subplots-adjust-py) to my D3 plot? Simply add a bar plot to the side? Is there a D3 module for this? Seem not to find any.

Comment: These were my [first](https://github.com/bmschmidt/colorbar) and [second](https://github.com/ttdtrang/d3-colorbar) search results, and you can see it being used [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic) as well - or have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63834014/5015356) about filling a thermometer with a gradient

Comment: Thanks, sometimes its better to repost the polished SO question into Google before submitting it seems...